# How would you make a distinction between general and user settings in the same settingspage?

Tags: settings

Imagine the following case in a planning tool: a planner works on a planboard where all candidates need to be planned for work. This board has settings. Most of these settings are applied only to this board, but the setting the user makes will be applied for all other planners as well (assuming this user has admin-rights). Yet, the settings also display 'Preferences'. These are planner-specific settings that will be applied to all boards, only for this user. As I designed it now, the difference is only shown through a divider line between the 2 kinds of settings but it's not very clear to the planners this way. I'm kind of struggling to find a way that will work for them. Any suggestions are more than welcome. Thx.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The divider line doesn't really express any hierarchy or relationship between the settings very clearly, so maybe the menu item should be called settings, and you can have a section for Board in which all the options that apply to all boards for the one user are displayed or listed (as submenu items), and a section for User in which all the options that apply to the user for all boards are displayed.

It also isn't clear whether you can choose to apply settings to just one board for one single user, so you'll have to consider that in designing the layout and creating the appropriate labels.